# how to make firefox stop downloading images once an event is performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, backbone.js

I have an application in backbone.js that displays thousands of images. Based on selecting a folder, the image that belongs to the folder will get displayed by hiding others. But the problem here is as soon as I open the app, the browser starts downloading every image as all images have source even though it is not displayed and thus it slows down the app. I fixed it in chrome and IE by removing the source of images that are not displayed so that the browser doesn't download it(I can add source later when it needs to be displayed by fetching the source from the backbone model). This works well in chrome and IE but not in firefox as firefox doesn't stop downloading the images even if the source is removed after loading the page.
I would really appreciate if anybody could give some suggestions on this to make this work in firefox.

Comment: So you can't control markup, can you?

Comment: Yes, I can control markup

Comment: You haven't provided any code in question so this is blind guess but you should be able to render markup such as `<img data-src="..." />` and later assign src from data attribute with something like `$(img).attr("src", $(img).data("src"));` (OK, maybe not exactly this one but you get the idea).

Comment: I am sorry for not making it clear. It is not possible that way. There is a folder called 'all images' where the issue occurs. When you chose that folder it needs to render all images. But when you select an image, the image will be used in the page where the app is opened from and then the app will be hidden. What I wanted to achieve is to get the browser stop downloading the images once an image has been selected from that folder so that it does not slow down. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Now I see. Check if this helps: http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did consider this before but I have limitations in using more third party libraries. Would be great if you could provide a solution that would not have to use a third party library.